# How to access sharedpreferences in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm using sherlock fragment in tab but I'm not able to access `sharedpreference` or save it, how can I? this is my code:

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockFragment  {

    private CheckBox cb1;
    private Context context = getActivity();
    private SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, container, false);
        cb1 = (CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    context.getSharedPreferences("some_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putBoolean("some_bool_name", true)
                    .commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Please also tell me how to save the preference if above method ain't correct.

**LogCat**

> 11-13 18:13:36.907: I/ActivityManager(10626): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myapp.test/.MainActivity} from pid 10836
>       11-13 18:13:36.907: D/ActivityManager(10626): TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.myapp.test activityName: com.myapp.test.MainActivity  bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
>       11-13 18:13:36.907: D/GuidanceScreen(10824): appName: My App, currentPkg: com.myapp.test, event: app_launch, controller: Keyboard
>       11-13 18:13:36.907: D/ActivityManager(10626): Showing guidance for pkgName: com.myapp.test
>       11-13 18:13:36.917: D/GuidanceScreen(10824): appName: My App
>       11-13 18:13:36.987: D/GuidanceScreen(10824): no guidance for com.myapp.test.
>       11-13 18:13:37.037: D/WindowManager(10626): Sending appClickStats request with data: [package=com.myapp.test, appname=My App, appver=1.0, clickloc=system_server]
>       11-13 18:13:37.237: I/ActivityManager(10626): Displayed com.myapp.test/.MainActivity: +260ms
>       11-13 18:13:46.227: D/AndroidRuntime(15464): procName from cmdline: com.myapp.test
>       11-13 18:13:46.227: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.myapp.test
>       11-13 18:13:46.227: D/AndroidRuntime(15464): file written successfully with content: com.myapp.test StringBuffer : ;com.myapp.test
>       11-13 18:13:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): Process: com.myapp.test, PID: 15464
>       11-13 18:13:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.myapp.test.SettingsActivity.onCreateView(SettingsActivity.java:40)
>       11-13 18:13:46.267: I/ActivityManager(10626): Process com.myapp.test (pid 15464) has died.
>       11-13 18:13:46.267: W/ActivityManager(10626): Force removing ActivityRecord{4b12da0c u0 com.myapp.test/.MainActivity t17}: app died, no saved state
>       11-13 18:13:46.287: I/WindowState(10626): WIN DEATH: Window{4b1ac890 u0 com.myapp.test/com.myapp.test.MainActivity}

Comment: What is problem? You got an error? Or data does not saved?

Comment: it force closes the app. when i try to access SP like that

Comment: please look at the question, i added logcat, maybe that might help!

Comment: if you comment `context.getSharedPreferences("some_pref", Context.MOD...`, are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, i got the above error with that.

Comment: what about this line `SettingsActivity.java:40` ? Please paste line number 40.

Comment: line 40 is `sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`

Comment: try comment this line: sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

Answer (score 0):

Initialize shared preferences:

```
private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
```

Inside onCreateView():

```
loginPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
```

Save:

```
loginPrefsEditor.putString("start_time", yourText);
loginPrefsEditor.commit();
```

Retrieve:

```
String dateString = loginPreferences.getString("start_time", "");
```

Comment: Look at the logcat in the question!